# python directory import issue on ROS

Tags: ros, python, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
My ros_workspace directory is like this:

ros_workspace --> src--> package1(src, msg, script((folder1-->abc1.py), ( folder2-->abc2.py))):

I want import "abc2.py" from "abc1.py", how should i write ?
I tried "import package1.script.folder2.abc2" from "abc1.py", it is so long for the path, also I use catkin_make under ros_workspace build, the error show "ImportError: No module named scripts.folder2"
How should i import the abc2.py from abc1.py ? please don't say "put abc1.py and abc2.py together", this is just a example, I have too many python files, so i need category them to several folder. thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268368/python-directory-import-issue-on-ros/) by [apanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29296/apanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would need to write `setup.py` and include `catkin_python_setup()` in CMakeLists as described in Section 1.2 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile). This would add your packages to PYTHONPATH when you source the workspace.

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0